# MySQL запрос многие ко многим

Tags: mysql

Приветствую!
Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос к mysql.

> Есть таблица с фирмами (firms) id |
> name | ... всякие поля ...
>
> Таблица с категориями (category) id |
> cat_name
>
> И таблица со связями (firms_category)
> firm_id | category_id

Нужно извлечь все фирмы из категорий, например с id 1,3,5

И еще усложним: если помимо категорий есть другие параметры, например способы оплаты.

> Таблица (payment_methods) id | p_name
>
> И таблица со связями (firms_payment)
> payment_id | firm_id

Как извлечь все фирмы из категорий 1, 3, 5 и способами оплаты 1, 4, 6

Так понимаю, нужно как то через join..
И вообще правильный ли это подход или есть способы проще?

Comment: > есть способы проще?

нету (эмуляцию джойна "вручную" считаю за джойн)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(f.name) 
from firm f, firm_cat fc, firm_pay fp
where f.firm_id = fc.firm_id
and f.firm_id = fp.firm_id
and fc.cat_id in(1, 3, 5)
and fp.pay_id in(1, 4, 6);
```

Вот так, по-моему, без `join`

Comment: Прочему -1?